find the coefficient $a_n$ of a power series
I have the power series
$$
f(z)=\frac{2}{(1-3z)^{\frac{2}{3}}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2},
$$
and I am supposed to find an explicit expression for the coefficient of the corresponding sum representation of the power series.
What I did so far:
$$
\frac{2}{(1-3z)^{\frac{2}{3}}}=2\cdot\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{\frac{-2}{3}}{n}\cdot 3^nz^n
$$
so the first part is already in a nice representation. For the second part I did
$$
e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)^n}{n!}
$$
according to the exponential series
this is then:
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}z^{2n}
$$
from which i cannot directly read $a_n$, since we have a $2n$ in the exponent of $z$
any idea on how i could proceed here?

Note that $$\sum_{n\geq 0} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}z^{2n}=\sum_{n\geq 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^n\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}z^{n}.$$

You need to work for $(n \bmod 2)=0$ and $(n \bmod 2)\neq 0$.. You can build a piecewise function
